# ActiveAdmin - Can a resource contain a custom block, AND be sortable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to basically have a toggle switch for a resource.... However when i pass the block as the second option, i can no longer sort by that column.

```
    column :Playable do |level|
        link_to level.playable || 'false', "levels/#{level.id}/toggle"
    end

 # ... later
    member_action :toggle do
        level = Level.find(params[:id]);
        level.update_attribute("playable", !level.playable)
        redirect_to(:back)
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
column :Playable, :sortable => :playable do |level|
  ...
end
```